# How to pivot a dataframe so the column labels become elements in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        Date        a45     a52     b28     ...     c75     c77     c78     
0       1/1/1981    -9999   9.473   8.987   ...     12.689  12.199  11.928 
1       1/2/1981    -9999   5.832   7.401   ...     14.001  13.327  13.323 
2       1/3/1981    -9999   4.248   5.025   ...     13.045  11.538  11.472 
3       1/4/1981    -9999   6.049   8.592   ...     15.421  14.208  14.319 
4       1/5/1981    -9999   -2.755  1.395   ...     13.289  11.701  11.684 
...     ...         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2127    7/27/2020   -9999   -1.708  1.603   ...     13.123  11.085  11.113 
2128    7/28/2020   -9999   1.623   4.770   ...     15.262  14.132  14.060 
2129    7/29/2020   -9999   1.042   3.118   ...     11.848  10.227  10.168 
2130    7/30/2020   -9999   3.716   5.778   ...     11.192  10.389  10.464 
2131    7/31/2020   -9999   2.019   6.944   ...     11.211  11.018  11.063
```

My goal is to pivot it but I can't figure it out. I want it to look like this

```
Date        site    temp
1/1/1981    a45     -9999
1/2/1981    a45     -9999
1/3/1981    a45     -9999
1/4/1981    a45     -9999
1/5/1981    a45     -9999
...         ...     ...
7/27/2020   c78     11.113 
7/28/2020   c78     14.060 
7/29/2020   c78     10.168 
7/30/2020   c78     10.464 
7/31/2020   c78     11.063
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at ``pandas.melt`` - ``df.melt('Date', value_name='temp', var_name='site')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new df that has the organization you want by iterating over the columns that are sites and collecting the site data, then append to your new df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/1981', '1/2/1981', '1/3/1981', '1/4/1981'], 'a45':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'a52': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
all_columns = df.columns.tolist()
all_columns.remove('Date')
for col in all_columns:
    df_site = df[['Date', col]]
    df_site['site'] = col
    df_site = df_site.rename(columns={col: 'temp'})
    df_new = df_new.append(df_site)

df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)
#        Date  temp site
# 0  1/1/1981     1  a45
# 1  1/2/1981     2  a45
# 2  1/3/1981     3  a45
# 3  1/4/1981     4  a45
# 4  1/1/1981     5  a52
# 5  1/2/1981     6  a52
# 6  1/3/1981     7  a52
# 7  1/4/1981     8  a52
```